# Как указать минимальную ширину страницы?

Tags: html, bootstrap, jsp

Есть меню, сверстанное на `bootstrap`. Можно ли ограничить минимальную ширину страницы  до `760px`, чтобы меню не ломалось?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navbar-my{

    background: #58ba5c;
    /*#b5cd60
    58ba5c*/    
}

#colorAMenu a{
   color: white; 
   font-size: 16px;
    
}

.navbar-my ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #4cae4c !important;
}

.navbar-my ul li a:focus{
    background-color: #4cae4c !important;
}

.navbar-my ul li a:active{
    background-color: #4cae4c !important;
}

.nav .open > a{
     background-color: #4cae4c !important;
}

#dropAColor a{
   /* background:#58ba5c; */
    color: black;   
}

#dropAColor a:hover{
   /* background:#58ba5c; */
    color: white;   
}



.pag{
margin-top: -15px;
margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.pag2{  
    margin-top: -35px;
    
}

/*.wrapper {
  width: 100%;

  min-width: 760px;
}*/

body{
  min-width: 760px;  
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style>
           <%-- <%@include file='css/bootstrap.min.css' %> --%>
            <%@include file='css/menu.css' %>  
            <%@include file='css/style.css' %>
            <%@include file='css/dropdownMenu.css' %>  
            
        </style>

       <!-- <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/3.2.1_jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquary_ui.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

    </head>
    <body class="wrapper">      

        <nav id="colorAMenu" class="navbar navbar-my">    
            <div class="container-fluid"> 
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdownMenu.js">
                    </script>
                    <a class="navbar-brand disabled" href="#">Бази даних. Перегляд</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!--Дата по умолчанию-->
                    
                    <li hover><a href="index.jsp" >Головна</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" hover>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Перегляд даних<span class="caret"></span></a> 
                        <ul id="dropAColor" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <%--<li><a href="SkisqlController?action=list&page=1">Перегляд бази Skisql</a></li>--%>
                            <li><a href="Search?page=1&count=0&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&kiz=${kiz}&svi=<%=curStringDate%>">Кількість одиниць складових(деталей) у виробі(VP44150SQL)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="SearchTmi?page=1&count=0&osdch=${osdch}&nc=${nc}&svi=<%=curStringDate%>">Технологічний маршрут виготовлення(TMISQL)</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Технологічний маршрут виготовлення(TMPSQL)</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="SearchTmpCh?page=1&count=0&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&cp=${cp}&svi=<%=curStringDate%>">Перегляд "Що"-"Куди"</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="SearchTmpK?page=1&count=0&osdch=${osdch}&osdk=${osdk}&cp=${cp}&svi=<%=curStringDate%>">Перегляд "Куди"-"Що"</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                </ul>  

                <!--Скрипт для подсказок-->      
                <script>
                    $(function () {
                        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
                    })
                </script>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <form class="frm" method="post" name="exit" action="login.jsp">
                            <!-- <button id="justbutton" class="btn  btn-sm btn-success navbar-btn " >Вихід</button>-->
                            <button id="justbutton" class="btn  btn-sm btn-success navbar-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Вихід" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вам нужно

Comment: @entithat Смотрите, на первом скрине нормальная меню, после того как уменьшить размер окна ниже 760px, меню подстраивается под размер окна, хотелось бы что бы появлялась горизонтальная прокрутка если размер окна меньше 760 px, и меню не менялось

Comment: Код не работает.

Comment: @dmitryshishkin а так? добавил ссылки на бутстрап и стили его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из файла `bootstrap.min.css` убертие все, что обернуто в медиа-выражение `@media (min-width: 768px)`

и для укажите минимальную ширину для боди

```
.body {
    min-width: 768px;
}
```

Comment: а тегу body можно назначить класс "wrapper"? сделал так `.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 760px;
}` не работает, появляется прокрутка горизонтальная, но меню все равно меняется(

Comment: Выложите ваш код, пожалуйста.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: это же явно bootstrap подстраивает размер меню как я понимаю, можно ли запретить это как-то, вот тут не знаю

Comment: @СергейНиконенко убрать из бутрстапа все медиа-выражения для 760 пикселей можно.

Comment: @СергейНиконенко обновил ответ

Comment: а, нет, так не сработает. Они от обратного ж делают.

Comment: Можно заменить `@media (min-width: 768px)` на `@media (min-width: 0px)`

Comment: спасибо, попробую после обеда, отпишусь

Comment: вроде как получилось, но вот еще вопросик, там у меня еще есть dropdown, подменюшка, вот при нажатии она ломается, когда размер меньше 768, а в css не могу найти под нее такое же свойство @media, не подскажете где его найти?

Comment: Все, нашел, спасибо большое за помощь)